# Sails.js on windows 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, failed-installation

I am trying to install sails.js on windows 8 x64 with `npm install sails` command. I've got an error MSB4025 with some *.vcxproj files. I suppose that this is an encoding issue.

I suppose that if I save these files in utf-8 installation will be successful, but if I run `npm install` again all files are replaced. Is there any way to run npm install without downlading sources once again?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is due to building native modules for npm on windows.
when it comes to sails, socket.io might be the issue here
take a look at the readme: https://npmjs.org/package/node-gyp

`vcxproj` is the extension of projects/project-files in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ (which you have to install)